# Unable to locate window - Selenium Webdriver error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch windows in selenium web driver but keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: 
Unable  to locate window "{519f3402-9039-4742-8cb3-4106fe8b24c4}"
```

Here is my code which part i am doing incorrectly .please help

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    WebDriver driver1=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    js.executeScript("window.open()");

    Set<String> WINDOWIDS= driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> iter=WINDOWIDS.iterator();    
    String Window1=iter.next();//Returns first window id
    String Window2=iter.next();//Returns second window id

    driver.switchTo().window(Window1);

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xyz@xyz.com");

    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("xyz@xyz.com");
```

Comment: Why are you creating two driver instances?

Comment: it wont create two windows but will create two drivers.

Comment: There is no need for window switch. you can use `driver` for facebook and `driver1` for google related operations respectively

Comment: if i open a new window using javascript still its is not happening

Comment: It ran without any error for me and there is no need to switch as the current focus in already on facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using `driver1.switchTo().window(Window1);`, here Window1 is window handle you got from driver(and NOT driver1). So you cannot use window handle from driver with driver1.

Try getting separate handles for driver1 and then switch to those set of windows only with driver1.(like  `Set<String> WINDOWIDS1= driver1.getWindowHandles();`)

Answer (score 0):

With your code I can able to run my script and able to pass those data into email id and password fields. It is working fine.

use WINDOWIDS.remove(window2);